# Bootstrap for goodness of fit

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, bootstrap, goodness-of-fit

Suppose I want to test whether a die is fair. I toss 60 times with outcome $X = (40,20,0,0,0,0)$ where $i$th coordinate denotes times of $i$th face occurs.Consider Hypothest test($\alpha = 0.05$): 
$$H_0: p_1 = p_2 = ... = p_6 = 1/6 \\
H_1: p_i \ne 1/6 ,for \ some \ i $$
consider test statistics $\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{(x_i - n/6)^2}{n/6}$ which has  approximately $\chi^2$ distribution with $5$ degrees of freedom where $x_i$ denotes times of $i$th face occurs.
I think I have to do a transformation to make original sample $X$ has mean $(10,10,10,10,10,10)$,then with this new sample $X_{new}$, do bootstrap,right?

Comment: What problem do you see with applying the usual chi-squared test exactly as you described?

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume more generally that the die you are rolling has $m$ sides. Then the statistic $\chi^2$ has an approximate $\chi^2(m-1)$ distribution **when the null hypothesis is true**. This approximation will improve as $m$ grows, and for $m=6$, this approximation will turn out to be pretty good (especially for the data you are interested in testing).

If you are worried about "how good" the chi square approximation is you can choose to approximate the null sampling distribution of $\chi^2$ empirically with Monte Carlo. (A proper bootstrap using the data doesn't really make sense in this setting, since the null hypothesis fully specifies the distribution). This MC approach can be performed in R as follows.

```
n <- 60      #How many trials 
m <- 6       #How many sides to the die
B <- 50000   #How many MC samples
samp_distr <- rep(NA, B)
for(i in 1:B){
  x <- sample(m, n, replace=TRUE)
  samp_distr[i] <- sum((table(x)-n/m)^2)/(n/m)
}
hist(samp_distr, freq=FALSE, breaks=20)
curve(dchisq(x, m-1), add=TRUE, lwd=2, col='orange')
```

Check out the fit for $m$ equal to $2$ (coin flip) and $6$. The chi-square approximation is already *decent* for $m=2$, and for $m=6$ it is really quite good. 
[image]
A p-value using the chi-square approximation can be obtained with the command

```
pchisq(test_stat, m-1, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

and empirically with the command

```
mean(samp_distr > test_stat)
```

As long as `B` is large enough in the code above, the Monte Carlo method will be "more correct" than the chi-square approximation. The benefit gained from sampling is negligible even for $m=2$, and the chi-square approximation is more than adequate.

Comment: +1.  For these data, using the classical chi-squared distribution has better theoretical justification and is more likely to be accurate than the bootstrap, too.

Comment: @whuber yes.I also use the classical chi-squared distribution.I want to do bootstrap to compare traditional method.Any hint to do bootstrap for this problem?

Comment: @Spaceship122 This method, while similar to a parametric bootstrap, requires no resampling from the data. I am just simulating draws from the null distribution, hence I hesitate to call this a bootstrap in the usual sense.

Comment: @whuber Interesting. Can you expand a little bit? Other than Monte Carlo error which can be reduced by doing a large number of simulations, I would have thought the sampling distribution constructed here is exact and therefore better than the chi-square approximation.

Comment: The bootstrap is an asymptotic procedure. It relies implicitly on the assumption that samples you draw from your data will behave essentially like samples from the population. In the present case, the data are so unbalanced that this is hardly a plausible assumption. I have no doubt bootstrapping--or even any statistical procedure that isn't out-and-out demented--will strongly conclude these data are not independent draws from a uniform distribution. But I would give more credence to what the chi-squared distribution tells me than to what the (easily predictable) bootstrap distribution would.

Comment: @whuber, I agree about the asymptotic nature of the bootstrap, but do you agree that my proposition isn't formally a bootstrap procedure? We just use Monte Carlo to obtain draws from the exact sampling distribution.

Comment: Sure, but why?  It's going to be extremely close to the chi-squared distribution because, as you have noted, that distribution is a "pretty good" (actually very good) approximation.  If you want to do any better, you might as well compute the full multinomial distribution directly rather than sampling.

Comment: @whuber Okay thank you for expanding. I agree completely and one of my main points was to show that the chi-square gives a very good approximation for this problem.